# Trying to get file names without path or extension and output to a list.

Tags: c#

Was given this by a coworker but I need just file names:

```
    private List<string> getWavFileList()
    {
        string path = @"c\test automation\wave files";

        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.wav");


        List<string> list = new List<string>(files);

        return list;

    }
```

The output list contains the path and extension and I need the file name only. I was working on my own method but can't get it to compile:

```
    private List<string> getWavFileList()
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        string path = @"c\test automation\wave files";
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.wav");
            foreach (FileInfo fi in smFiles)
            {
                builder.Append(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
                builder.Append(", ");
            }

            string files = builder.ToString();

            List list = new List<string>(files);

            return list;
```

Comment: Did the compiler happen to mention any reason in particular why it won't compile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest modifying to something like the following;

```
private List<string> getWavFileList()
{
    string path = @"c:\test automation\wave files";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    FileInfo[] smFiles = di.GetFiles("*.wav");
    List<string> list = new List<string>(smFiles.Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f.Name)));

    return list;
}
```

Comment: That won't compile either

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, correct, I missed the non-generic `List` from the source. I've updated.

Answer (score 2):

In the first solution replace this line

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(files);
```

with this:

```
return files.Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```

This requires using of `System.Linq`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are concatenating strings with comma, i thought you wanted a list:

```
private List<string> getWavFileList()
{
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"c\test automation\wave files", "*.wav")
        .Select(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension)
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it.

Comment: Would be slightly better if it was `EnumerateFiles`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: ok, edited, but OP used also `GetFiles` and i didnt want to change uncommented which doesnt improve noticeably. I would have used if he had to filter the files.

Comment: I know, didn't want to put that as an answer either. A discussion about iterators, IEnumerable, temporary objects and GC would be a bit over the top. Unless there were quite a *lot* of files